# Organizing separate articles and chapters in calibre

Tags: metadata, calibre

I've got quite many texts, which are only part of specific publications: mostly articles from magazines and scanned chapters from books.

It is unclear how to assign metadata to them. Should I use book name in "series" field? Should I make multiple copies with full book data for each article, and extend book titles with article titles? Both ways are quite inconvenient.

What is the designated way to organize such texts? Or if there is none, how do you do it?